# Finding method of moments

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Question:

[image: Question]

In order to solve find the method of moments estimator, I know I need to first find the expected value of Y. But after finding $E(Y)= \frac{\theta}{2}$, what should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the population moment by sample analog to obtain $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i = \frac{\hat \theta}{2}$ and so $$\hat \theta = \frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i$$